# Shaders miss after install new version Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I install new version of Unity3d (5.3.1p2) and all objects became pink (all materials has Standard shader).[Pink color of shaders in inspector](http://prntscr.com/9omx3l)
Get error in console:
GpuProgram creation error: shader program type is unrecognised. You might have a precompiled shader asset from an old Unity version.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the Library folder of your project ? It should force Unity to recompile eveything

Comment: I try delete the Library folder: error again.

Comment: i usually get pink shaders when the mesh or prefab is missing, check if all what the shader needs is still in the asset folder and linked to the component using the shader

Comment: All shaders exists in asset folder